# Exclude tags in questions

Tags: support, tags, newest-questions

Is there a way to view the "newest questions" section with excluded tags? E.g.

*Show all C#-tagged questions but not those which are also tagged with WPF*

Comment: I.e. possible but no UI support?

Comment: Search for `[C#] -[WPF]` and you get a list of newest questions with the one tag but not the other.

Comment: The other option is to add `WFP` to your ignored tags, and set ignored tags as hidden (not just faded out).